# undefined method `encoding_aware?'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I resolve this issue in rails 4. I upgraded my project from rails 3 to rails 4.

My server console is throwing me below error message. Could not figure out.

```
     undefined method `encoding_aware?' for #<String:0x000000053e6ca0>
```

Code :

```
  module ActionView
   class Template
   module Handlers
     class ERB
      def call(template)
        if template.source.encoding_aware?   # here is the error
```

Error Log:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `encoding_aware?' for #<String:0x00000004b05348>:
  config/initializers/10-patches.rb:63:in `call'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:270:in `compile'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in compile!'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `compile!'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  rack-mini-profiler (0.9.1) lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:108:in `block in profile_method'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
```

my config/initializers/10-patchers.rb file
   require 'active_record'

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include Redmine::I18n
    # Translate attribute names for validation errors display
    def self.human_attribute_name(attr, *args)
      attr = attr.to_s.sub(/_id$/, '')

      l("field_#{name.underscore.gsub('/', '_')}_#{attr}", :default => ["field_#{attr}".to_sym, attr])
    end
  end

  # Undefines private Kernel#open method to allow using `open` scopes in models.
  # See Defect #11545 (http://www.redmine.org/issues/11545) for details.
  class Base
    class << self
      undef open
    end
  end
  class Relation ; undef open ; end
end

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module DateHelper
      # distance_of_time_in_words breaks when difference is greater than 30 years
      def distance_of_date_in_words(from_date, to_date = 0, options = {})
        from_date = from_date.to_date if from_date.respond_to?(:to_date)
        to_date = to_date.to_date if to_date.respond_to?(:to_date)
        distance_in_days = (to_date - from_date).abs

        I18n.with_options :locale => options[:locale], :scope => :'datetime.distance_in_words' do |locale|
          case distance_in_days
            when 0..60     then locale.t :x_days,             :count => distance_in_days.round
            when 61..720   then locale.t :about_x_months,     :count => (distance_in_days / 30).round
            else                locale.t :over_x_years,       :count => (distance_in_days / 365).floor
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class Resolver
    def find_all(name, prefix=nil, partial=false, details={}, key=nil, locals=[])
      cached(key, [name, prefix, partial], details, locals) do
        if details[:formats] & [:xml, :json]
          details = details.dup
          details[:formats] = details[:formats].dup + [:api]
        end
        find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
      end
    end
  end
end

# Do not HTML escape text templates
module ActionView
  class Template
    module Handlers
      class ERB
        def call(template)
          if template.source.encoding_aware?   # HERE IS THE ERROR LINE
             # template.source.encoding_aware?
            # encoding_aware? method has been deprecated or moved

            # First, convert to BINARY, so in case the encoding is
            # wrong, we can still find an encoding tag
            # (<%# encoding %>) inside the String using a regular
            # expression
            template_source = template.source.dup.force_encoding("BINARY")

            erb = template_source.gsub(ENCODING_TAG, '')
            encoding = $2

            erb.force_encoding valid_encoding(template.source.dup, encoding)

            # Always make sure we return a String in the default_internal
            erb.encode!
          else
            erb = template.source.dup
          end

          self.class.erb_implementation.new(
            erb,
            :trim => (self.class.erb_trim_mode == "-"),
            :escape => template.identifier =~ /\.text/ # only escape HTML templates
          ).src
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new{ |html_tag, instance| html_tag || ''.html_safe }

require 'mail'

module DeliveryMethods
  class AsyncSMTP < ::Mail::SMTP
    def deliver!(*args)
      Thread.start do
        super *args
      end
    end
  end

  class AsyncSendmail < ::Mail::Sendmail
    def deliver!(*args)
      Thread.start do
        super *args
      end
    end
  end

  class TmpFile
    def initialize(*args); end

    def deliver!(mail)
      dest_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'emails')
      Dir.mkdir(dest_dir) unless File.directory?(dest_dir)
      File.open(File.join(dest_dir, mail.message_id.gsub(/[<>]/, '') + '.eml'), 'wb') {|f| f.write(mail.encoded) }
    end
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :async_smtp, DeliveryMethods::AsyncSMTP
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :async_sendmail, DeliveryMethods::AsyncSendmail
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :tmp_file, DeliveryMethods::TmpFile

# Changes how sent emails are logged
# Rails doesn't log cc and bcc which is misleading when using bcc only (#12090)
module ActionMailer
  class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
    def deliver(event)
      recipients = [:to, :cc, :bcc].inject("") do |s, header|
        r = Array.wrap(event.payload[header])
        if r.any?
          s << "\n  #{header}: #{r.join(', ')}"
        end
        s
      end
      info("\nSent email \"#{event.payload[:subject]}\" (%1.fms)#{recipients}" % event.duration)
      debug(event.payload[:mail])
    end
  end
end

module ActionController
  module MimeResponds
    class Collector
      def api(&block)
        any(:xml, :json, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActionController
  class Base
    # Displays an explicit message instead of a NoMethodError exception
    # when trying to start Redmine with an old session_store.rb
    # TODO: remove it in a later version
    def self.session=(*args)
      $stderr.puts "Please remove config/initializers/session_store.rb and run `rake generate_secret_token`.\n" +
        "Setting the session secret with ActionController.session= is no longer supported in Rails 3."
      exit 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you go through error backtrace and post the exact line of code throwing this error?

Comment: Hey Shivam. I updated my question with error log and code please help me on how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: What is `config/initializers/10-patches.rb` ? Please show us the whole file. It appears to be what is causing this problem.

Comment: Ryan Bigg I added that file as well. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`encoding_aware?` is [deprecated in Rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/String/encoding_aware%3F).

If you take a quick look at the [Rails 3 source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/String.html#method-i-encoding_aware-3F) for the `String` class you can find the implementation:

```
def encoding_aware?
  true
end
```

So to fix your issue you can simply define the missing method by extending the `String` class, or find and replace any instances of calls to `encoding_aware?` with `true`.

This is how the extension would look:

```
class String
  def encoding_aware?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Mike Slutsky! Where should I define the missing method. In which file?

Comment: Any of the files in your `config/initializers` directory will work, you just need to make sure it's loaded before the call to `encoding_aware?` happens. So I would probably try adding it to the top of `config/initializers/10-patchers.rb`, I'll add the block of the code to the answer.